# Get the REMOTE_ADDR in Django-Rest-Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to get the request's remote_addr?

I have a `BileModelListAPIView` as bellow:

```
class BileModelListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = BModelSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = BileModel.objects.all()

    def get(self, request):

        print(request) # there I debug the point
        return Response(data="ok", status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

[image]

I read an article that says that the HttpRequest have a META property, in META there is REMOTE_ADDR.

But in my scenario how can I get the REMOTE_ADDR?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You haven't said why you need that but if you want to get client's IP then `Remote-Address` is not reliable. It will return server IP if user is behind proxy or your server is behind reverse proxy.

`X-Forwarded-For` is a more reliable way to get client's IP. It will return multiple IP addresses in case of multiple proxies between client and your webserver.

`X-Forwarded-For` is included in the META attribute as well, but sometimes servers aren't configured to include `X-Forwarded-For` header. In this case you're left with `Remote-Address`.

The code:

```
x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
if x_forwarded_for:
    ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
else:
    ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
```

This code will get IP either from the first IP in the X-Forwarded-For or Remote-Address if X-Forwarded-For header is not available.

Comment: When doing this on localhost I only get 127.0.0.1. Shouldnt I be getting my actual IP address

Comment: @Aseem, what do you mean your actual IP? Actual IP of the localhost is 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @Borut By actual IP Address I think he meant his Public IP.